# Java - DocumentBuilder Throws Exception On Creation

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom

I'm getting a "XMLEntityScanner$(Throwable)" error when debugging in Eclipse on this line: 
**DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();**

Here is the full code:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbFactory.setValidating(true);
dbFactory.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(products); // load xml file
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting this. I'm using this tutorial as reference.

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/

Comment: Full stack trace will help...

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to do this in Eclipse. I changed the catch to grab all exceptions and print the stack, but it's not printing anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it wasn't an error at all, I'm just unfamiliar with Eclipse. It's just an error that it can't find the source for the function during debug.